# Synchronizing threads java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading and have some trouble synchronizing two threads.

I'm reading data from a tag which I then want to do calculations on in another thread, so my phone can continue communicating with the tag and not have to wait for the calculations to be done. The relevant code basically looks like this:

```
public void f() {
//...some stuff
for (byte[] data : dataObject) {
     byte[] response = tag.transive(data); //exchange data with tag
     CalculcationThread calc = new CalculationThread(data, card);
     calc.start();
}
card.setReady(true);

wait(); //wait for all calculations to have finished

//do some stuff based on calculations
}
```

CalculationThread:

```
public class CalculationThread extends Thread {
    ...
@Override
    public void run() {
//do calculations, then
       if(card.isReady()) {
           notify(); //notify main thread that all calculations are complete
       }
   }
}
```

I know that you need to put wait and notify in a synchorized block or add the synchronized tag to the method, but I still can't seem to figure out how to correclty synchronize these threads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using wait/notify incorrectly, but you don't even need it here. Just call `calc.join()` and it'll resume when the thread is done. And make sure `setReady()` is writing to a `volatile` field if it's used for inter-thread communication.

Comment: Looks like you will also need an array/collection of `CalculationThread`, then after the loop, iterate through this array calling `join` on each Thread.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Good point, I missed the loop. You might want to use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) then.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

```java
notify(); //notify main thread that all calculations are complete
```

That `notify()` call happens in the `run()` method of a `CalculationThread` instance. There's no object specified on which to call `notify()`, so you are implicitly calling `this.notify()` (i.e., you are calling `notify()` on a `CalculationThread` instance.)

The corresponding `wait()` also does not specify any object, so there, you are implicitly calling `this.wait()`. But what is `this`? The call happens in a method named `f()`, but what class does `f()` belong to?

A call to `o.notify()` in one thread will have no effect on some other thread that's waiting in a `p.wait()` call if `o` and `p` are different objects.

You said you were having some trouble synchronizing, but you never said what the "trouble" actually was. If the trouble was, `wait()` never returned, then is it possible that the object you `notify()`ed was not the same object that was `wait()`ing?

Comment: I imagine the trouble was the exception thrown by calling `wait()` or `notify()` without first synchronizing.